# Tkinter scrolledtext, how to set slider visible by default

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

[image]

I am using a scrolledtext widget in my application and would like the slider to be visible when the application opens. Any help appreciated.

Edit:
Here is a sample of me setting up my scrolledtext widget.

```
    def init_actions(self):
    """"""
    inp = ' '
    self.sText = tkst.ScrolledText(self.st_frame, height=20,
                                   width=40)
    self.sText.pack(ipadx=5, ipady=2, fill=tki.X)
    self.sText.insert(tki.INSERT, inp)
    self.sText.bind("<Key>", self.key)
    self.sText.tag_config('cmd', foreground='red')
```

I have been trying to configure the scrollbar to show the slider when the app opens. All attempts thus far have used my scrolledtexts vbar widget. I tried playing with the relief setting and I also tried using activate().

```
self.sText.vbar.config(relief=tki.GROOVE)
self.sText.vbar.config(relief=tki.RAISED)

self.sText.vbar.activate('slider')
```

I

Comment: Add some code to your question. -[MCVE]

Comment: Also, show us what you've researched. -[Asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What would you expect the slider to actually DO, when there's not enough text to need scrolling?  I guess you could give the field some initial contents consisting of a lot of newlines...

Comment: I have been working with the text input mainly so far, and kind of learning as I go. The scrollbar; not showing the slider in a default state, has been bugging me. I looked through the example on effbot.com and didn't see anything directly related to setting the default state of the slider. (on route for second look).   I tried printing the keys and looked into cursor and relief. I am playing with others now and still no joy

Comment: Just seen the comment @jasonharper. I guess I just want it for cosmetic reasons :). It would serve no functional purpose unless the windows full. I just noticed it wasn't there and ended up down a rabbit hole.